# is installing node modules in your systems root folder that same as adding the -g flag to the module

Tags: node.js

I normally use my terminal and install packages in my systems root folder so I can access them globally, but I also see people use the -g flag when installing packages.

I would like to know the difference between the 2 and which one is better suited for actually making packages global.

Comment: Well some modules even require extra manual modifications on *Windows System* to get them working; but for the rest if you can install them simply by using `-g` flag why would you do it the more verbose way. Is there a specific scenario/reason why you are asking that?

Comment: hello, just wanted to know whether it was wrong to do it the way i've been doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by the root folder?

if you mean the npm global folder `/usr/lib/node_modules`, then technically no. This is *technically* no different than globally installing the package. However, this is not the correct way to install the packages globally and could cause issues. It's easier and safer to just use `npm -g`

If you mean the actual system's root directory `/`, this is not the same as globally installing a package and can DEFINATELY cause problems on your system. Stop doing this asap.

If you mean your project's root folder, then that's just installing the package locally.

In terms of your actual question, use `npm -g`, as npm was designed to install global packages this way. It is also likely easier than cd-ing all the way to whichever folder you are mentioning and installing the module manually.